# alter drop cockroach db contrain

Tags: constraints, cockroachdb, drop

ALTER TABLE public."users" DROP   CONSTRAINT users_un;
error :
ERROR: unimplemented: cannot drop UNIQUE constraint "users_un" using ALTER TABLE DROP CONSTRAINT, use DROP INDEX CASCADE instead
Hint: You have attempted to use a feature that is not yet implemented.
See: https://go.crdb.dev/issue-v/42840/v21.1

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to do DROP INDEX CASCADE on the index that corresponds to the constraint.

If you need the specific command, please provide the output to `SHOW CREATE public.users`.